# What does "File stack underflow!" mean?

Tags: warnings, standalone, currfile

I am getting two times the error:

> Package currfile Warning: File stack underflow! on input line xxx.

I am not explicitly loading `currfile`, but standalone seems to do.

I am getting this warning once after I load `\usepackage{standalone}` on a line, where a working if-directive is written (`\ifclolor ... \fi`) and once in the `standalone.sty` after `\RequirePackage{currfile}` on the line `\ifsa@subpreambles`.

I don't know, what that warning means, so I don't know, what to search for. This message is not treated anywhere so far.

**Edit:**
After some searching I found out that it appears when loading `unicode-math` AND `standalone`

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{standalone}    
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
Nothing
\end{document}
```

Comment: `currfile` maintains a stack for referring to the file currently being read. I guess that the warning is issued if the macros try to access the stack and find it empty. Without an example showing the issue not much more can be said.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. It took me some time, but I got you an MWE.

Comment: I get no warning if I load `currfile` (or `standalone`) before `unicode-math`.

Comment: Fair enough. Works for me, too. Thanks. Should I inform Martin or Will/Khaled? Or is that some documented behavior, I haven't found yet?

Comment: I think Martin should take a look at this. I'll try to contact him in chat.

Comment: @egreg, LaRiFaRi: I will have a look at it once I find time. I

Comment: @MartinScharrer Is there a general feature of package loading sequences which might cause this error? I'm getting it though I'm not using `unicode-math`. I guess I need to load `standalone` earlier but I'd like to figure out earlier than what because the 'what' is a wrapper around `beamer.cls` so it means some messing around.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Any progress here? The issue appeared again: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278868

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: I guess the `scrreport` class is changing the definition of `\input` or related macros. Our workaround to load the package with `\RequirePackage{currfile}` before the `\documentclass` is a good way to avoid it. I will try to debug that, but in general there is no 100% solution to have it working as everyone can overwrite everything ;-)

Comment: @MartinScharrer Any news?

Comment: @egreg: I had a lock on it now. Has nothing to do with `scrreport`, `unicode-math` or `xetex`, but simply with loading `filehook` before `currfile`. I get the same *warning* with this MWE: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filehook}
\usepackage{currfile}
\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warning is caused by `currfile` in an at-end hook because it tried to restore the parent file name which was not available. This is the case if `currfile` is loaded by another package and not in the main file.

`currfile` requires `filehook` and installs corresponding at-begin and at-end hooks for all files. If `filehook` is not already loaded before the hooks will only be affected by all files opened afterwards. However, if it is already loaded, the at-end hooks of `currfile` and the package which loads it, and the package which loads that package, and so on, are executed while the at-begin hooks are already executed before `currfile` patched them. This leads to a stack underflow.

A workaround is to load `currfile` very early yourself in the preamble, before `filehook` is loaded by any package or class.

As I see no real way to avoid the stack underflow in this case and it is not a problem and no underflow should occur in any other case, I now remove the warning altogether. In that case the `\currfilename` macros where always empty. I now changed them to hold the main file name.
I will publish these changes as a new version soon.

See the official [bug ticket](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/currfile/issues/4/file-stack-underflow-when-used-with) for further information.

Comment: Submitted `currfile` v0.7c 2015/04/23 now to CTAN. Should be there in a day or two. Mirrors might need an extra day. Distributions like MikTeX and TeXLive will update it usually in one week after that.