# File stack underflow problem

Tags: warnings, currfile

I was wondering if this is a bug in the currfile package. I am getting warning: `File stack underflow!` while running the given code.

Also, I run into warnings: `Font shape 'OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available(Font) size <5> substituted`.

Can any one help me with getting rid off the warnings? I tried both on Miktex 2.9 in a Windows PC and a Mac, and both gives me similar warnings.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{currfile}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Hello World} 
  Minimum Working Example
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\RequirePackage{currfile} % fixing 1st warning.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern} % fixing 2nd and 3rd warning. 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Hello World} 
    Minimum Working Example
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The issue is also mentioned in an [earlier post of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135341). I will try to inform Martin Scharrer about this.